# How to hide system volume bars in flutter app when pressing hardware volume buttons?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My app counts by pressing volume buttons. When I press a button, along with counting, system volume bar appears. I want to disable/hide system volume bar in my flutter counter app. I'm using hardware_buttons 1.0.0 to listen to volume buttons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide UI when volume up down pressed in a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335026/hide-ui-when-volume-up-down-pressed-in-a-dialog)

Comment: have you find any solution..?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible because the volume button press events handled by OS itself. And as an app, it can only listen to those events.

I'm not sure that there might be some trick or hack to do this, please enlighten me if there is.