# How to hide the volume bar programatically in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So, I am making an app that makes use of volume keys and upon pressing them, the volume bar should not appear. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563208/android-hide-volume-change-bar-from-device?r=SearchResults), but for some reason, it didn't work. While the sound doesn't get updated (because of `return true` in the `onKeyUp()` event), the volume bar still appears. Have I made a mistake somewhere in the code? How can I fix this?

P.S: I also added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />` but, like I said, it still doesn't work

Java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;
    RelativeLayout rl;
    int n=1;
    int nmax;
    AudioManager am;
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
            if(n<nmax) {
                //am.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                am.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                n++;
                tv.setText(""+n);
                return true;
            }
        }else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
            if(n>1){
                //am.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                am.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                n--;
                tv.setText(""+n);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nmax = runnables.length;
        am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);


        tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText("1");

        rl = findViewById(R.id.rl);
        rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                runnables[n-1].run();
            }
        });
    }
    Runnable[] runnables = {null,null,null,null,null};
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#6000FFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In other words, you want your app to take away common functionality on MY device? I like my volume bar. This is one way for your app to have its payment canceled.

Comment: @NomadMaker all I want to do is to **hide** the volume bar. When it comes to functionality of raising the volume up or down, that doesn't matter. Also, it's not going on the play store or anything, I'm making it for myself.

Comment: Then that should have been explained in your question. As it is, I still think it is a bad decision from a UX standpoint.